# Excel VBA script - Matching cells value with a pre-defined pattern

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a vba script for excel. I want to restrict the user's input in a range of cells to only allow EXACTLY a number, followed by a dash and another number or a single number only. The validation should only allow the following 2 types of inputs:

12-500
or
12

I know this can be done via excel's in-built data validation however I'm trying to look for another option via vba script.

The only idea I came up with is using something like this:

If Not cell.Value Like "[A-Z]" Then

I Just started using VBA so I can't seem to understand how to implement this in code.

Comment: Are you looking for another method just for the intellectual challenge? Better to use the inbuilt optimized tool otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I am. Trying to do data validation via scripts instead of the inbuilt tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, Worksheet change event will allow you to validate cell value and apply the logic.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'When Value in "A1 changes"

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" And Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
          Target.NumberFormat = "@"

        'put logic to restrict

        If checkStr(Target.Value) = False Then
            Target.Value = ""
        End If
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub


Function checkStr(ByVal str As String) As String

    Dim objRegEx As Object, allMatches As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With objRegEx
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[0-9-]"
    End With


    Set allMatches = objRegEx.Execute(str)
    checkStr = (allMatches.Count > 0)

End Function
```

Comment: The code seems to work fine however every time I try to input a numeric value with a dash afterwards excel changes the cell's data type/format to date (dd-mmm)automatically even though I keep removing it.

Comment: I believe you may have entered a date in that cell earlier and so the formatting. Reset the formatting and try again.

Comment: Resetted the formatting multiple times also opened new worksheets. When entering values such as 12-12 excel automatically turns it into a date even though the formatting is not set to date.

Comment: Thanks, It works wonderfully. By any chance can the .Pattern be edited to only allow 2 types of values in the cell? I want the user to only be allowed to input either a single number or a range of numbers. For example input is restricted to either "12" or "12-40", without any extra dashes or anything.

Comment: I changed the .pattern to "[0-9][-][0-9]" and it works for the "12-40" example however I can't seem to integrate this to work with a number only. I tried by using the OR operator, "[0-9]|[0-9][-][0-9]", however when I use this values such as "12--" and "12-" are allowed

Comment: You can simply validate specific text using if condition. Also, you can play with regex here https://regex101.com/  I am not good with regex.

Comment: Try `.Pattern = "^(\d+-)?\d+$"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to validate if input is between 0 and 9.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="9"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

You can change this function for your needs.

HINT: you will need to use **Type:=xlValidateCustom,** and you will need only Formula1 where you need to describe your logic. You dont need Formula2

HINT2: to select range of cells use

```
Range("D3:M30").Select
    With Selection.Validation
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. May I ask how do I apply the validation for a specific range of cells please? I started using VBA a few days ago so I'm still learning.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The "Range("D3:M30").Select" keeps actively selecting the range of cells specified whenever I click anywhere in the sheet. Can this be mitigated?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method that doesn't rely on the in-built validation or regex:

```
Function validateInput(i As String) As Boolean
Dim a() As String
If Not i = "" Then a = Split(i, "-") else Exit Function
If Not UBound(a) = 1 Then Exit Function
If Not IsNumeric(a(0)) Then Exit Function
If Not IsNumeric(a(1)) Then Exit Function
validateInput = True
End Function
```

Just creates a temporary array, attempts to split on the "-", if no "-" then not valid, if too many "-" then not valid, if not "isnumeric" for first half or 2nd hald, then not valid!